# jQuery check mousemover every x ms

Tags: jquery, timer, mousemove

I use the function mousemove({}). I want this mousemove function to be called only if it was last called at least 1second ago. I know I may use some kind of timer and put a condition

```
if( cur_time - last_time > 1)
  do_the_stuff();
```

1. Is there a better method of doing this?
2. If not, what is the function I should use to get cur_time (or to get time passed) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds like a good approach.  Your code should look something like this:

```
var last_moved;
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    if (!last_moved || (e.timeStamp - last_moved > 1000)) {
        do_the_stuff();

        last_moved = e.timeStamp;
    }
});
```

See [a working example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bY3CC/4/).

Comment: For me it's working kind of strange on the jsFiddle... I'll have a look

Comment: @Cristy I've fixed the obvious problem, which was that the handler wasn't activated on the first mouseover.  Have a look at the new link.

Comment: Ok, I found your "bug" :D http://jsfiddle.net/bY3CC/3/ The last_moved must be uptaded only inside the if() because that's when the "last_move" is happening :D

Comment: @Cristy Fair enough, if that's what you wanted. I was interpreting your requirements as "if the mouse has been still for 1 second", which is admittedly not what you asked for!  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Another problem, in my examples the message seems to be updated even if the mouse is still... Seems like the "mousemove" is called too when the mouse is still

Comment: Ok, then this sounds like another question to be asked :D

Answer (score 0):

No that seems to be the best way to do it. Put that statement within the mousemove and you should get what you need.

Comment: Ok, how do I use the timer? How can I get cur_time ?

Comment: Call setTimeout() on page load; capture the last_time in a global variable.